# Absolute path for flutter assets

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I find an absolute path for flutter assets? After some googling, I found  `file:///android_asset/flutter_assets/assets` for android, but what would be for iOS? Is there any API to get the assets path for all platforms?

Comment: have you found a solution?